# Passing a boolean from a listener to enclosing function

Tags: python

Here is a simple snippet of a much larger program I am working on. The `decideByKeypress()` is a function that waits for either an Esc key or for a combination of left `Ctrl` and left `Shift`. The first keyboard interaction means success, hence the `return 0` while the latter means something is wrong, hence the `return -1`. (The user will see ML classification input-output pairs on the screen and this snippet helps the user to decide if the classification is correct or not.)

Since the listening process must be broken first, I obviously couldn't add the aforementioned return statements directly there. This is why `on_press` returns `False` in both the `Esc` and the `Shift+Ctrl` cases.

I added a boolean variable `escPressed` to clearly separate the two cases. A `True` is assigned to it if `<Key.esc: <27>>` is found in the current set, and a `False` is assigned in the other case.

Now, having `escPressed`, I hoped I can merely add an if/else condition and return 0 or -1 based on the truth or falsehood of `escPressed`. However, when running the code and pressing `Esc`, it seems to me that the `True` value set to `escPressed` is ignored, as if the internal `escPress` wouldn't see the already defined, outer `escPressed`. I am very surprised by this behavior as a variable declared inside a function can be accessed by functions inside that function, as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

Here is the full code:

```
from pynput import keyboard


COMBINATIONS = [
    { keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.ctrl_l },
    { keyboard.Key.esc }
]

def decideByKeypress():
    current = set()
    escPressed = bool()

    def on_press(key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
                print(current)
                if keyboard.Key.esc in current:
                    escPressed = True
                    return False
                elif (keyboard.Key.shift_l in current) and (keyboard.Key.ctrl_l in current):
                    escPressed = False
                    return False
                else:
                    pass

    def on_release(key):
        try:
            current.remove(key)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

    if escPressed:
        print("Esc has been pressed!")
        return -1
    else:
        print("Esc has not been pressed!")
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    decideByKeypress()
```

And here are my outputs I got when pressing `Esc`:

```
{<Key.esc: <27>>}
escPressed is set to True
Esc has NOT been pressed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the actual implementation of `keyboard.Listener` but something in it apparently causes `escPressed` to be visible to only the `on_press` function (it is probably executed on a separate thread).

A quick way to solve this will be to keep track of the state in a mutable/shareable data-structure, for example, a `dict`.

```
state = {'esc': False}

def decideByKeypress():
    current = set()

    def on_press(key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
                print(current)
                if keyboard.Key.esc in current:
                    state['esc'] = True
                    return False
                elif (keyboard.Key.shift_l in current) and (keyboard.Key.ctrl_l in current):
                    state['esc'] = False
                    return False
                else:
                    pass

    def on_release(key):
        try:
            current.remove(key)
        except KeyError:
            pass

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

    if state['esc']:
        print("Esc has been pressed!")
        return -1
    else:
        print("Esc has not been pressed!")
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    decideByKeypress()
```

running and pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>:

```
{<Key.esc: <27>>}
Esc has been pressed!
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a ton for your help, @DeepSpace!